# Convert a string to a hexadecimal number saved in a int variable

Tags: string, function, integer, decimal, hex

I need a function that can convert a string containg numbers to a hexadecimal integer saved in an integer variable,
for example the function atoi(char*) converts the string in that string into a decimal number , what i need is something similar but instead of decimal , hexadecimal

Answer (score 1):

All integers store data in the same format: binary. That is neither decimal or hexadecimal.

If you want to create a string from an integer, that's when you can decide if you want decimal or hexadecimal notation.

You didn't mention what language you are using so I'll just assume C or C++ from the atoi() reference. There is also an itoa() function. It will create a string from an integer, and you can specify if the string will be created using base 16, base 10, or something else.

Comment: I am using c++, the atoi() takes in a string as a parameter and if it contains digits then it converts it in a decimal integer stored in a varialble what I need is a function thats is similar in every way but instead of converting to decimal integer , its converted to a hexadecimal integer stored in a variabl

Comment: No, again, that's not what atoi() does. It converts it to a binary value. You only see a decimal value because you might be using a debugger or other tool that automatically converts it to a string using base 10. I don't know how to make it any clearer than that.